# Downgrade DirectX 11 to 9.0c (Win7)

Tags: windows-7, directx, sdl, directx-11

My Windows7 has DirectX 11 as default.
But I have trouble with DirectX 11 when I use SDL2.0
The solution is downgrading DirectX 11 to 9.0c (googling result)

Is there any method for downgrading?
I couldn't find DirectX 11 in 'program add/remove'
So I can't remove DirectX 11 in 'program add/remove'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SDL 2.0 library to develop your application, you have three steps to config it.

- Include SDL.h at the beginning of you program
- Link sdl2.lib and SDL2main.lib in your project settings
- Put SDL2.dll in your project directory(or put it in you System32 directory, so every project can
  use it)

please take a look at the tutorial on this [page](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php) for details. although it is for SDL 1.2, you can easily apply it for SDL 2.0.

If you want to build SDL 2.0 source code, you should install the DirectX SDK, since SDL 2.0 has a renderer based on DirectX 9.0

> My Windows7 has DirectX 11 as default.

Your Windows7 also have DirectX 9.0 runtime library d3d9.dll, the DirectXruntime libraries was shipped with Windows7 in System32 folder.

> I couldn't find DirectX 11 in 'program add/remove'

You can only find it after you install the DirectX SDK

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, DirectX is a core component of the operating system and cannot be manually removed.  If you are having trouble with specific DirectX 11 hardware, you can try updating the hardware drivers via the vendor's website, or disabling the hardware in Device Manager.